# tesseract misslead black <-> white

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Good tool but some errors  are making me disappointed.
I'm using tesseract for single character recognition

This image  recognized as ":"
[image: This picture]

This image  recognized as "."
[image]

This image  recognized as "."
[image]

What can I tweak to improve quality?
Looks like the colors are in reverse somehow. How can I instruct tesseract that text is black?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how you use tesseract? What font? Any other settings?

Comment: use only one option --psm 10 
I have a lot of small images with 1 char in each.

Comment: No, black text on white background is the default.

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: just CLI usage 
tesseract  --psm 10 image.png